# redirect or php equivalent of HttpResponse.TransmitFile?

Tags: php, apache2

I need to take in a url and use an external app (written in another language, i am to lazy to rewrite it) to map it to the true filename and directory. I'd like to serve these files normally. I have flv files and others that need to be seekable. The mime should be as apache normally serves. What command can i use/How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess with a bunch of rewrite rules would do the trick.

Comment: I have root access to the box. Would i be able to rewrite by grabbing the url by spawning a cmd line process?

Comment: No. You configure the server by...configuring the server. Apache docs explain this better than I could.

Comment: i cant use this then bc theres dozens of if's and > 100 special characters and escapes. (no exaggeration)